# How to set the background color for files of different types in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, settings

**settings.json** allows to define the background color for all files:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
 "editor.background": "#F0F8FF" }
```

Is it possible to set different background colors, for example, for files with extensions **html**, **php** and **js** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in features of VSCode do not allow you to customize the background color depending on the file type.
There is an extension [Theme by language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsaulou.theme-by-language). It allows you to customize the theme of VSCode depending on the programming language.

Answer (score 2):

With the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) you can change that theme color based on languageID or file location.